# Spring, using new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and getting error being unable to find applicationContext.xml and others?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html to use annotation dependency injection in my application. I set up the bean, etc like in the tutorial and then am trying to get an instance of the bean within my MainController class (a controller class that  handles generating a specific page for my spring web mvc app).. I keep getting

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I am doing this in my MainController:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    BeanFactory factory = context;
    BeanIRPlus beanirPlus = (BeanIRPlus) factory
            .getBean("BeanIRPlus");
    IRPlusInterface irPlus = beanirPlus.getIRPlus();
```

I have searched and searched on this and yet to find an answer that fixes my problem. My applicationContext in in webapp/WEB-INF/ and my spring app seems to be working otherwise as it was handling requests, etc before this. I have tried putting the applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF classes but still nothing. Is there any workaround to make this not search the path this way as I think its doing a relative path search. Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but here goes.

The tutorial you have referred is for dependency injection in a standalone application and not a web application.  In case of web application, spring automatically loads the context files and initializes the beans. So you would not need any of the lines specified in the `MainController`.

Instead, you could do something like this to use beanIRPlus bean in your controller.

```
@Autowired
private BeanIRPlus beanIRPlus;
```

Comment: wow ok thats an eye opener :), thanks for the help, am going to try it now without that.. so how do I actually use the bean within the MainController if I need to call a method on it? Any advice / resources for this are appreciated, I have been spending hours and hours looking over things on this but sometimes miss important things like what I just did as I'm still learning.. thanks

Comment: Thank you for all your help.. I have seen the @Autowired thing before but its hard when new to spring to put 2 and 2 together sometimes as it seemed each tutorial was talking about a different way to do it (probably because some were for non-web)