# Spring classpath issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm trying to set up a Spring application to run in eclipse for the first time. I'm running it at as a standalone java application. The app builds without any errors but when I go to execute it, I get a ClassNotFoundException with the following stack trace:

```
DataLoadService [Java Application]  
    com.pikefin.services.DataLoadService at localhost:52871 
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 217    
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 205 
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 321   
            Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 294    
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 266    
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).<init>(ApplicationContext) line: 161 
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext).<init>(ApplicationContext) line: 90   
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext).<init>(ApplicationContext) line: 59 
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(AbstractXmlApplicationContext).<init>(ApplicationContext) line: 61   
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(String[], boolean, ApplicationContext) line: 136  
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(String) line: 83  
            DataLoadService.main(String[]) line: 20 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/java (Nov 6, 2012 1:14:23 PM)
```

It's happening on this line of code:

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
```

spring.xml gets moved into the class/ folder during the build process so I tried adding the class folder to the launch configuration (see screenshot).

[image]

I'm working with eclipse 3.7.2 and spring 3.1.1

Comment: You write `ClassDefNotFound` but your paste shows `ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the spring libs. This issue is about the project build path and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `spring` but the following is suspicious:

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
```

Perhaps it should be

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

For example, in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012636/spring-using-new-classpathxmlapplicationcontext-and-getting-error-being-unable) the usage is

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Unless your file is actually called `classpath:spring.xml`, not `sprint.xml`, but I doubt that.

Comment: I tried removing the classpath: prefix but still getting the same error.